# Fedex WS API testing - Open Shipment

Tags: xml, api, fedex

Been trying to understand how to create Open Shipments from Fedex Documentation.
An example of an Open Ship request that works would be helpful, as far as I've gotten is "Requiring a Consolidation Key". Although I can't find examples of Consolidation keys to try.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v18="http://fedex.com/ws/openship/v18">
 <soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <v18:CreateOpenShipmentRequest>
 <v18:WebAuthenticationDetail>
 <v18:UserCredential>
 <v18:Key>KEY**</v18:Key>
 <v18:Password>PASS**</v18:Password>
 </v18:UserCredential>
 </v18:WebAuthenticationDetail>
 <v18:ClientDetail>
 <v18:AccountNumber>ACCOUNT#**</v18:AccountNumber>
 <v18:MeterNumber>METER#**</v18:MeterNumber>
 <v18:Localization>
 <v18:LanguageCode>EN</v18:LanguageCode>
 <v18:LocaleCode>en</v18:LocaleCode>
 </v18:Localization>
 </v18:ClientDetail>
 <v18:TransactionDetail>
 <v18:CustomerTransactionId>8006665550555</v18:CustomerTransactionId>
 <v18:Localization>
 <v18:LanguageCode>EN</v18:LanguageCode>
 <v18:LocaleCode>en</v18:LocaleCode>
 </v18:Localization>
 </v18:TransactionDetail>
 <v18:Version>
 <v18:ServiceId>ship</v18:ServiceId>
 <v18:Major>18</v18:Major>
 <v18:Intermediate>0</v18:Intermediate>
 <v18:Minor>0</v18:Minor>
 </v18:Version>
 
 <v18:RequestedShipment>
 <v18:ShipTimestamp>2021-02-05T00:00:00-00:00</v18:ShipTimestamp>
 <v18:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</v18:DropoffType>
 <v18:ServiceType>INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY_DISTRIBUTION</v18:ServiceType>
 <v18:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</v18:PackagingType>
 <v18:TotalWeight>
 <v18:Units>LB</v18:Units>
 <v18:Value>250.0</v18:Value>
 </v18:TotalWeight>
 <v18:TotalDimensions>
 <v18:Length>12</v18:Length>
 <v18:Width>12</v18:Width>
 <v18:Height>12</v18:Height>
 <v18:Units>IN</v18:Units>
 </v18:TotalDimensions>
 <v18:Shipper>
 <v18:AccountNumber>703101976</v18:AccountNumber>
 <v18:Tins>
 <v18:TinType>BUSINESS_NATIONAL</v18:TinType>
 <v18:Number>INDIVIDUAL</v18:Number>
 </v18:Tins>
 <v18:Contact>
 <v18:PersonName>AMAR</v18:PersonName>
 <v18:CompanyName>SYNTEL</v18:CompanyName>
 <v18:PhoneNumber>1234567890</v18:PhoneNumber>
 <v18:EMailAddress>Amarnadh_Chennmsetti@syntelinc.com</v18:EMailAddress>
 </v18:Contact>
 <v18:Address>
 <v18:StreetLines>80 Fedex Prkwy</v18:StreetLines>
 <v18:StreetLines>Suite 101</v18:StreetLines>
 <v18:City>BOGOTA</v18:City>
 <v18:StateOrProvinceCode>DC</v18:StateOrProvinceCode>
 <v18:PostalCode>110311</v18:PostalCode>
 <v18:CountryCode>CO</v18:CountryCode>
 <v18:Residential>false</v18:Residential>
 </v18:Address>
 </v18:Shipper>
 <v18:Recipient>
 <v18:Contact>
 <v18:PersonName>via FEDEX IED</v18:PersonName>
<v18:CompanyName>Syntel</v18:CompanyName>
<v18:PhoneNumber>9017977100</v18:PhoneNumber>
 </v18:Contact>
<v18:Address>
 <v18:StreetLines>2903 SPRANKEL AVE</v18:StreetLines>
<v18:City>MEMPHIS</v18:City>
 <v18:StateOrProvinceCode>TN</v18:StateOrProvinceCode>
 <v18:PostalCode>38199</v18:PostalCode>
<v18:CountryCode>US</v18:CountryCode>
<v18:Residential>false</v18:Residential>
<v18:GeographicCoordinates>+0.0+0.0/</v18:GeographicCoordinates>
 </v18:Address>
 </v18:Recipient>
 <v18:Origin>
 <v18:Contact>
 <v18:PersonName>RAVI</v18:PersonName>
<v18:CompanyName>SYNTEL</v18:CompanyName>
<v18:PhoneNumber>7896543210</v18:PhoneNumber>
<v18:EMailAddress>Ravikumar_Sharma@syntelinc.com</v18:EMailAddress>
 </v18:Contact>
<v18:Address>
 <v18:StreetLines>80 Fedex Prkwy</v18:StreetLines>
<v18:StreetLines>Suite 101</v18:StreetLines>
<v18:City>BOGOTA</v18:City>
<v18:StateOrProvinceCode>DC</v18:StateOrProvinceCode>
<v18:PostalCode>110311</v18:PostalCode>
<v18:CountryCode>CO</v18:CountryCode>
<v18:Residential>false</v18:Residential>
 </v18:Address>
 </v18:Origin>
 <v18:ShippingChargesPayment>
 <v18:PaymentType>SENDER</v18:PaymentType>
<v18:Payor>
 <v18:ResponsibleParty>
 <v18:AccountNumber>703101976</v18:AccountNumber>
<v18:Contact>
<v18:PersonName>Amar</v18:PersonName>
<v18:CompanyName>Fedex</v18:CompanyName>
<v18:PhoneNumber>1234567890</v18:PhoneNumber>
<v18:EMailAddress>amar.ch@gmail.com</v18:EMailAddress>
 </v18:Contact>
<v18:Address>
 <v18:StreetLines>80 Fedex Prkwy</v18:StreetLines>
<v18:StreetLines>Suite 101</v18:StreetLines>
 <v18:City>BOGOTA</v18:City>
 <v18:StateOrProvinceCode>DC</v18:StateOrProvinceCode>
<v18:PostalCode>110311</v18:PostalCode>
<v18:CountryCode>CO</v18:CountryCode>
<v18:Residential>false</v18:Residential>
 </v18:Address>
 </v18:ResponsibleParty>
 </v18:Payor>
 </v18:ShippingChargesPayment>
 <v18:ConsolidationDetail>
 <v18:RelationshipTimestamp>2021-02-05T01:42:48-06:00</v18:RelationshipTimestamp>
 <v18:Type>INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY_DISTRIBUTION</v18:Type>
<v18:Role>MASTER_AIRWAYBILL_SHIPMENT</v18:Role>
<v18:InternationalDistributionDetail>
 <v18:SummaryDetail>
 <v18:TotalWeight>
 <v18:Units>LB</v18:Units>
<v18:Value>250.0</v18:Value>
 </v18:TotalWeight>
 <v18:TotalPackageCount>5</v18:TotalPackageCount>
 <v18:TotalUniqueAddressCount>1</v18:TotalUniqueAddressCount>
<v18:TotalCustomsValue>
 <v18:Currency>USD</v18:Currency>
 <v18:Amount>2500.0</v18:Amount>
 </v18:TotalCustomsValue>
 </v18:SummaryDetail>
 </v18:InternationalDistributionDetail>
 </v18:ConsolidationDetail>
 <v18:CustomsClearanceDetail>
 <v18:CustomsOptions>
 <v18:Type>OTHER</v18:Type>
<v18:Description>Consolidatedproduct</v18:Description>
 </v18:CustomsOptions>
<v18:ImporterOfRecord>
 <v18:AccountNumber>703101976</v18:AccountNumber>
<v18:Contact>
 <v18:PersonName>swapnil</v18:PersonName>
<v18:CompanyName>Syntel</v18:CompanyName>
<v18:PhoneNumber>9985621496</v18:PhoneNumber>
<v18:EMailAddress>Swapnil_Ghadage@syntelinc.com</v18:EMailAddress>
 </v18:Contact>
<v18:Address>
 <v18:StreetLines>2 INTERNATIONAL PL</v18:StreetLines>
<v18:StreetLines>IPD TESTING FXRS</v18:StreetLines>
<v18:City>Memphis</v18:City>
<v18:StateOrProvinceCode>TN</v18:StateOrProvinceCode>
<v18:PostalCode>38117</v18:PostalCode>
 <v18:CountryCode>US</v18:CountryCode>
<v18:Residential>false</v18:Residential>
 </v18:Address>
 </v18:ImporterOfRecord>
<v18:RecipientCustomsId>
 <v18:Type>COMPANY</v18:Type>
<v18:Value>125</v18:Value>
 </v18:RecipientCustomsId>
<v18:DutiesPayment>
 <v18:PaymentType>SENDER</v18:PaymentType>
 <v18:Payor>
 <v18:ResponsibleParty>
 <v18:AccountNumber>703101976</v18:AccountNumber>
<v18:Contact>
 <v18:PersonName>Amarnadh</v18:PersonName>
<v18:CompanyName>SYNTEL</v18:CompanyName>
<v18:PhoneNumber>1234567890</v18:PhoneNumber>
<v18:EMailAddress>Amarnadh_Chennmsetti@syntelinc.com</v18:EMailAddress>
 </v18:Contact>
 <v18:Address>
 <v18:StreetLines>2 INTERNATIONAL PL</v18:StreetLines>
<v18:StreetLines>IPD TESTING FXRS</v18:StreetLines>
<v18:City>Memphis</v18:City>
<v18:StateOrProvinceCode>TN</v18:StateOrProvinceCode>
<v18:PostalCode>38117</v18:PostalCode>
<v18:CountryCode>US</v18:CountryCode>
<v18:Residential>false</v18:Residential>
 </v18:Address>
 </v18:ResponsibleParty>
 </v18:Payor>
 </v18:DutiesPayment>
<v18:DocumentContent>NON_DOCUMENTS</v18:DocumentContent>
<v18:CustomsValue>
 <v18:Currency>USD</v18:Currency>
<v18:Amount>2500.0</v18:Amount>
 </v18:CustomsValue>
<v18:InsuranceCharges>
 <v18:Currency>USD</v18:Currency>
<v18:Amount>1000.0</v18:Amount>
 </v18:InsuranceCharges>
<v18:PartiesToTransactionAreRelated>false</v18:PartiesToTransactionAreRelated>
<v18:CommercialInvoice>
 <v18:TermsOfSale>DDP</v18:TermsOfSale>
 </v18:CommercialInvoice>
<v18:Commodities>
 <v18:Name>product</v18:Name>
<v18:NumberOfPieces>1</v18:NumberOfPieces>
<v18:Description>product</v18:Description>
<v18:CountryOfManufacture>US</v18:CountryOfManufacture>
<v18:Weight>
 <v18:Units>LB</v18:Units>
<v18:Value>10.0</v18:Value>
 </v18:Weight>
<v18:Quantity>1.0</v18:Quantity>
<v18:QuantityUnits>X</v18:QuantityUnits>
<v18:UnitPrice>
 <v18:Currency>USD</v18:Currency>
 <v18:Amount>1000.0</v18:Amount>
 </v18:UnitPrice>
<v18:CustomsValue>
 <v18:Currency>USD</v18:Currency>
<v18:Amount>1000.0</v18:Amount>
 </v18:CustomsValue>
 </v18:Commodities>
<v18:ExportDetail>
 <v18:ExportComplianceStatement>30.37(f)</v18:ExportComplianceStatement>
 </v18:ExportDetail>
 </v18:CustomsClearanceDetail>
 <v18:BlockInsightVisibility>false</v18:BlockInsightVisibility>
 <v18:LabelSpecification>
 <v18:LabelFormatType>COMMON2D</v18:LabelFormatType>
<v18:ImageType>PNG</v18:ImageType>
 <v18:LabelStockType>PAPER_4X6</v18:LabelStockType>
 <v18:LabelPrintingOrientation>TOP_EDGE_OF_TEXT_FIRST</v18:LabelPrintingOrientation>
 </v18:LabelSpecification>
 <v18:RateRequestTypes>LIST</v18:RateRequestTypes>
 <v18:EdtRequestType>ALL</v18:EdtRequestType>
 <v18:PackageCount>1</v18:PackageCount>
 <v18:RequestedPackageLineItems>
 <v18:SequenceNumber>1</v18:SequenceNumber>
<v18:GroupNumber>0</v18:GroupNumber>
<v18:GroupPackageCount>1</v18:GroupPackageCount>
<v18:TrackingIds>
 <v18:TrackingIdType>FEDEX</v18:TrackingIdType>
<v18:FormId>0431</v18:FormId>
<v18:TrackingNumber>794999198509</v18:TrackingNumber>
 </v18:TrackingIds>
<v18:Weight>
 <v18:Units>LB</v18:Units>
<v18:Value>250.0</v18:Value>
 </v18:Weight>
<v18:Dimensions>
 <v18:Length>12</v18:Length>
<v18:Width>12</v18:Width>
<v18:Height>12</v18:Height>
<v18:Units>IN</v18:Units>
 </v18:Dimensions>
 <v18:CustomerReferences>
 <v18:CustomerReferenceType>CUSTOMER_REFERENCE</v18:CustomerReferenceType>
<v18:Value>abcfdggalkewgr</v18:Value>
 </v18:CustomerReferences>
 </v18:RequestedPackageLineItems>
 </v18:RequestedShipment>
 </v18:CreateOpenShipmentRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And Here is the response I have been getting back:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <CreateOpenShipmentReply xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/openship/v18">
        <HighestSeverity>ERROR</HighestSeverity>
        <Notifications>
            <Severity>ERROR</Severity>
            <Source>ship</Source>
            <Code>3791</Code>
            <Message>Consolidation Key required.</Message>
            <LocalizedMessage>Consolidation Key required.</LocalizedMessage>
        </Notifications>
        <TransactionDetail>
            <CustomerTransactionId>8006665550555</CustomerTransactionId>
            <Localization>
                <LanguageCode>EN</LanguageCode>
                <LocaleCode>en</LocaleCode>
            </Localization>
        </TransactionDetail>
        <Version>
            <ServiceId>ship</ServiceId>
            <Major>18</Major>
            <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
            <Minor>0</Minor>
        </Version>
    </CreateOpenShipmentReply>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: Has anyone had experience with working with Fedex Open Ship requests in XML? It's not the easiest documentation to understand unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Fedex has admitted to a bug being in their Developer - Test key environments specifically with OPEN SHIPMENTS. They have suggested that I could either do this testing straight in production or change the type from: INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY_DISTRIBUTION to FEDEX_GROUND and the consolidation key error will stop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).